# jQuery datatable search highlight not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm using jQuery datatable in our application to show tables. Now we want to highlight the search text which are searched by jQuery's in-built search textbox.

We are using jQuery's own site for [reference](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-10-22#Feature-plug-in).

Below is our code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/dataTables.searchHighlight.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.highlight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dataTables.searchHighlight.min.js"></script>
<script th:inline="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#pspTable').DataTable({
        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
        searchHighlight: true
    });
} );
</script>
```

However, whenever I'm running the application it's throwing the following error:

> TypeError: jQuery.highlight is not a function

This is referencing to following code segment of jquery.highlight.js:

```
return this.each(function () {
        jQuery.highlight(this, re, settings.element, settings.className);
    });
```

Is there some bug in the library or I'm missing something here? Please help me with it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `jQuery(this).highlight({ .... })`?

Comment: not working man :(

Answer (score 1):

Please open your developer tools and inspect the "Network" tab. It seems that `jquery.highlight.js` wasn't loaded, because this error will only be printed if the necessary highlighting function isn't available.

I also recommend you to use [`datatables.mark.js`](https://github.com/julmot/datatables.mark.js/) instead of `jquery.hightlight.js` as it's cross-browser unit tested, maintained and because it uses [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) there are many options you can use.

Comment: Tried with mark js...however then showing following error: TypeError: $(...).unmark is not a function. I am using jquery.mark.min.js and datatables.mark.js. Both of them loaded successfully.Am I doing something wrong in here? Do I need to include mark.min.js also?

Comment: No, if you've included jquery.mark.min.js everything should be fine. There's no need to also include mark.min.js. Can you prepare a minimal zip with a simple HTML and including all asset files you've mentioned in the question? Then I can determine the problem.

Comment: `datatables.mark.js` is actually quite nice, and descent programming as well. Did not knew that plugin before.

Comment: @AbhinabKanrar I need a zip containing the HTML and all assets. Only with that I'm able to check file loading issues and debug the application. It's not possible via JSBin

Comment: @AbhinabKanrar Can you provide the zip?

Comment: would share shortly

Comment: Did you forget it?

Comment: Won't be able to help you anymore.